# Afrikaans collator data missing from ICU 57.1?

Tags: icu

I am working on a C++ project which depends on ICU 57.1 for its collator service. As part of this project, I would like to create a .dat ICU archive file that includes all collator data. The ICU data library customizer tool (http://apps.icu-project.org/datacustom/) clearly shows that there is a collation tailoring for Afrikaans in the coll/af.res file. The ICU locale explorer also shows that the Afrikaans locale has a tailoring of the Unicode Collation Algorithm given by the following rule:

&N <<< ʼn

However, when I inspect the source/data/in/icudt57l.dat from a download of the 57.1 source code, it doesn't seem to include coll/af.res:

```
$ eval $(./source/install/bin/icu-config --invoke=icupkg) -l source/data/in/icudt57l.dat | grep af.res
af.res
curr/af.res
lang/af.res
rbnf/af.res
region/af.res
unit/af.res
zone/af.res
```

coll/af.res similarly seems to be missing if I build ICU from source using --with-data-packaging=files.

Am I doing something wrong or is there an actual problem with the ICU data?

Comment: Is there a Dutch?  If so, would it suffice?  Is there a default collation?  (I'm looking at MySQL's collations; Afrikaans and Dutch are not split out.)